# Java compressing try/catch codes exceptions

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, java.util.scanner

Is there any way to compress the try/catch block codes? Right now, my code has a try/catch code inside a try/catch code.

```
if(petType.equals("DOG")) {

  try {
    String name = input.next();
    String owner = input.next();
    double weight = input.nextDouble();
    SimpleDateFormat stdDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

    try {
      Date vaccineDate = stdDate.parse(input.next());
      boolean fixed = input.nextBoolean();
      Dog x = new Dog(name,owner,weight,vaccineDate,fixed);
      object.addPet(x);
    } 
    catch (ParseException ex) {
      System.out.println("ERROR - Vaccine date " + input.next() + " is not in mm/dd/yy format!");
      input.nextLine();
    }

  }
  catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
    System.out.println("ERROR - Missing fields. Skipping line " + lineNumber + "...");
    input.nextLine();
  }

}
```

Comment: You can use Java 7 multi-cache exception syntax : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java7exceptions-486908.html

Comment: Thanks! Found out my answer here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this

```
if(petType.equals("DOG")) {

  try {
    String name = input.next();
    String owner = input.next();
    double weight = input.nextDouble();
    SimpleDateFormat stdDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    Date vaccineDate = stdDate.parse(input.next());
    boolean fixed = input.nextBoolean();
    Dog x = new Dog(name,owner,weight,vaccineDate,fixed);
    object.addPet(x);
  }
  catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
    System.out.println("ERROR - Missing fields. Skipping line " + lineNumber + "...");
    input.nextLine();
  }
  catch (ParseException ex) {
    System.out.println("ERROR - Vaccine date " + input.next() + " is not in mm/dd/yy format!");
    input.nextLine();
  }
}
```

Or with Java 7

```
try {
...
} catch(ParseException | NoSuchElementException ex) {
...
}
```

If that's what you meant by compression.

Comment: Yep! That's what I meant. It was weird having a try/catch block inside a try/catch block

Answer (score 3):

1st of all, a single try block can be followed by a series of catch blocks:

```
try {
    throw IOException("msg");
    ...
    throw InterruptedException("msg");
}
catch (IOException ioe){
    ...
 } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    ...
 }
```

This is not the best practice, because you might want to narrow your try/catch blocks to handle smaller content of code regarding the Exceptions

Answer (score 1):

You can only use one try block, and then use catch(Exception ex) to catch all those exceptions. If you want to react to the specific kind of exception, you have to test for it.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do it (see below). But you might want to think about the structure of your code, for example, maybe you can restructure so that you don't have to call input.nextLine in each catch block.

```
if(petType.equals("DOG")) {

  try {
    String name = input.next();
    String owner = input.next();
    double weight = input.nextDouble();
    SimpleDateFormat stdDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");

    Date vaccineDate = stdDate.parse(input.next());
    boolean fixed = input.nextBoolean();
    Dog x = new Dog(name,owner,weight,vaccineDate,fixed);
    object.addPet(x);    
  }
  catch (ParseException ex) {
    System.out.println("ERROR - Vaccine date " + input.next() + " is not in mm/dd/yy format!");
    input.nextLine();
  }
  catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
    System.out.println("ERROR - Missing fields. Skipping line " + lineNumber + "...");
    input.nextLine();
  }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like nesting try/catch blocks.  I wouldn't write it this way; I'd prefer it more like this:

```
if(petType.equals("DOG")) {

  String vaccineDateString;
  try {
      String name = input.next();
      String owner = input.next();
      double weight = input.nextDouble();
      DateFormat stdDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
      stdDate.setLenient(false);
      vaccineDateString = input.next();
      Date vaccineDate = stdDate.parse(vaccineDateString);
      boolean fixed = input.nextBoolean();
      Dog x = new Dog(name,owner,weight,vaccineDate,fixed);
      object.addPet(x);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Vaccine date " + vaccineDateString + " is not in MM/dd/yy format!");
        input.nextLine();
    } catch(NoSuchElementException ex) {
        System.out.println("ERROR - Missing fields. Skipping line " + lineNumber + "...");
        input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

I would also look askance at your mingling input with all this other stuff.  I'd find another way.